# Time complexity for while loop

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of

```
x = 1
while( x < SomeValue )
{
    x *= 2;
}
```

I believe it is O(N), as the loop will continue for a fixed number of iteration.
Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I don't mind being wrong, but just that if I am wrong then what is the right answer.

Comment: If it's a fixed number of iterations, how many is it?

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity would be O(log(n)) because `x` is increasing exponentially.

Comment: Unless `SomeValue <= 1`, in which case complexity is O(1).

Comment: @cybersam You could apply that argument to any big O notation. If you specify the value of `n`, you can always solve it to a constant, thereby turning it into O(1).

Comment: If SomeValue > 1, then the complexity is `O(log(SomeValue))`, not `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will execute in O(log *n*) time.  Hopefully the math makes the reasoning more clear.  Each iteration is constant time.  To find the number of iterations relative to `SomeValue`, which we'll call *t*, you can see that after the *n*<sup>th</sup> iteration, `x` will have the value 2*ⁿ*.  The loop ends once `x`≥*t*.  So to find the number of iterations needed to meet or exceed *t*, plug in 2*ⁿ* for `x` and solve for *t*.  You get *t*=log₂(*n*).  Hence, O(log *n*) time.